# Facebook , custom settings isn't working on facebook

Tags: facebook

On Facebook I have 10 to 15 people on my custom list so they can not see my posts . Yet , when I post a status , one of the people I have on my custom list likes my status even though I had them on custom which they can not see it , when I post a status it shows a friend sign next to the status which means all my friends can see it , please help me !! I don't know why it's doing that !!! Please help?

Answer (score 2):

You need to put people you don't want to see your posts into the acquaintances list and make sure that you are posting to the following list:

[image]

If you post to any of the other lists they'll be able to see and comment on things that you post.

Keep in mind also that if you're currently looking at a custom or default list (like `Close Friends` or your work list) that if those people are in those lists they'll be able to see those posts.